# What is this tiny translucent insect on my shiso leaf?

Tags: pests

Some leaves on my shiso plant were thinned and white at places.

[image: a damaged leaf]

I looked at one of them with a small microscope (around x400) and detected this guy busy chewing:

[image: live insect chewing on my leaf]

Apparently his kind has caused lots of damage at macro and micro levels, including some galls too:

[image: gall on the underside of a leaf]

Could someone please tell me what kind of insects are they and how to treat them?